# Affine Model for inflation expectations

Tags: python, affinetransform

How would I code for the affine model to extract pure inflation expectations from data on nominal and real yields of bonds? I want to extract the risk premium and convexity of risk preferences from the break even inflation to get pure expectations.

I have been told to use python for this but have limited experience.

Comment: How would you code for any other model? What makes this particular model more difficult to code for you than any other model?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have no prior experience in modelling in python or in affine models in general. This model allows me to examine inflation expectations of different lengths at different dates@mkrieger1